# The sentence: In Palestine, many specialists train abroad. Is this with or without the comma inserted i this example?

Tags: commas

Is the comma correctly inserted in the sentence:

> In Palestine, many specialists are trained abroad.

Or is it without a comma?

Comment: I recommend you instead use a sentence with a clear unambiguous meaning.  Either *Many foreign specialists are trained in Palestine.* or *Many specialists in Palestine have trained abroad.*, depending on whether "in Palestine" refers to the location of the specialists or of the training.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the answer is yes,**you should use that comma** there because is interrupts the flow of the sentence.